# Nuget package HotTowel.Angular.Breeze installation fails in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, hottowel

I'm trying to install the nuget package HotTowel.Angular.Breeze in Visual Studio Community 2015.

The installation fails with the error:

> Die Datei "C:\Users\Holger.nuget\packages\HotTowel.Angular.Breeze\2.3.3\content\scripts\breeze.to%24q.shim.js" konnte nicht gefunden werden.

German for "File not found".

I found a file `breeze.to$q.shim.js` in this folder.

I installed the required packages Breeze.Server.WebApi2, HotTowel.Angular, Breeze.Angular, that worked.

However, when I try to install HotTowel.Angular.Breeze again, the installation fails with the same error.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Looks like it dislikes the `$` in the file name. Probably needs to be fixed by the package author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug in NuGet 3](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1117) which should hopefully be fixed in NuGet 3.2. NuGet 3 is url escaping paths which can cause problems installing content files with special characters.

NuGet 2.8.7 can install HotTowel.Angular.Breeze 2.3.3 without any errors. So the only workaround would be to use an older version of NuGet, which would also mean not using Visual Studio 2015, but Visual Studio 2013 or another IDE, such as Xamarin Studio or SharpDevelop.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I downloaded the HotTowel.Angular and Breeze packages separately, that worked and seems to be sufficient so far..

Answer (score 0):

I should also remove the `breeze.to$q.shim.js` as it was deprecated a long time ago and should not be used.